# Image not saving in Database in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to store image into database after it has been converted to base64 and also decoded. The image stores inside the Storage path but does not save into mysql database.
What am i doing wrong?

```
public function updateProfileImage(Request $request)
    {
        $user = auth('api')->user();

        $image = $request->input('image'); // image base64 encoded
        preg_match("/data:image\/(.*?);/",$image,$image_extension); // extract the image extension
        $image = preg_replace('/data:image\/(.*?);base64,/','',$image); // remove the type part
        $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
        $imageName = 'profile' . time() . '.' . $image_extension[1]; //generating unique file name;
        Storage::disk('public')->put($imageName,base64_decode($image));        
        $user->update($request->all());

}
```

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ The Image which is something like this 'profile929292929.jpg'

Comment: @TobiFerdinand what does the `$fillable` section look like in your User model?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$user = auth('api')->user();

if ($request['image']) {
    $data = $request['image'];

    list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
    list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
    $image = base64_decode($data);
    $photoName = 'profile' . time() . '.' . $image_extension[1];
    $request['image'] = $photoName;

    Storage::disk('public')->put($photoName, $image);
    $user->update($request->all());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this

```
public function updateProfileImage(Request $request)
    {
        $user = auth('api')->user();

        $image = $request->input('image'); // image base64 encoded
        preg_match("/data:image\/(.*?);/",$image,$image_extension); // extract the image extension
        $image = preg_replace('/data:image\/(.*?);base64,/','',$image); // remove the type part
        $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
        $imageName = 'profile' . time() . '.' . $image_extension[1]; //generating unique file name;
        Storage::disk('public')->put($imageName,base64_decode($image));


        $user->update($request->except('image') + [
            'profilePicture' => $imageName
        ]);
}
```

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use uploader packages like:

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary
or
https://github.com/alaaelgndy/FileUploader

to help you in media management without writing all these lines of code in every place you want to upload files.

enjoy them.

Comment: Bad idea.. he should use that code and make his own helper or trait because it's a very basic thing and installing a package is like killing a cow for a piece of meat. And the most important thing, after 1-2 laravel updates the package will not work anymore. I don't say you should never install packages but just choose your packages wisely!